# Access files via autogenerated ID through REST API

Tags: document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, indexed-column

what I'm currently doing is accessing the files in my Document Library through the REST API like this:
`[baseURL]/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('[relativeURL]')`. To collect these relativeURLs, I first need to crawl through the directories first, which is quiet clumsy.

I've noticed that there's also an option to access them through the GUID:
`[baseURL]/_api/Web/GetFileById('[guid]')`. However this doesn't seem much easier.

I've noticed that every file gets assigned a numerically index ID by default. E.g:

[image]

Is there a way to access the files through this ID column via the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query list items by ItemId, use REST API endpoint such as this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List Name')/items(" + ItemId + ")
```

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that SharePoint considers Document Libraries as something completely different than Lists and as such this method of access was not available.